# Touch Event in Core Plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-plot

I am using this code for touch event but its not working

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

how can i add touch event in core plot or i want to show bar graph values on top of each bar. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this topic in google forum](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=168), for touch event the delegate method which you are using should work. Check if the mistake is something related to setting the delegate or so. Check the `CPTestApp` application for an example.

For the second question, as [mentioned here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/coreplot-discuss/4eJ1JX451gw), in order to show the bar graph values on top of bar you can add simple labels by setting the `barLabelTextStyle`. You can also look at the following bar plot datasource method:

```
-(CPTextLayer *)barLabelForBarPlot:(CPBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex: 
(NSUInteger)index;
```

Again check `CPTestApp` for an example. You can use the `barLabelOffset` property to 
set the space between the ends of the bars and the labels as mentioned there.

Comment: If you are facing any issues with those solutions, you can also try posting in those two questions in the coreplot forum. They should be able to help you since that is just focused on coreplot alone.